# Mono mkbundle on Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: macos, mono, mkbundle

I'm trying to get the mkbundle tool working on Mac OS X 10.7. I installed XCode 5, a handful of different Mono versions, going from v2 to v4. Everytime I try to compile my code I get a

```
sh: as: command not found
```

When I try to find this command, its not on my system either. After googling, which is pretty hard as "as" is filtered out for being too generic, I simply cannot find a solution to this. The best resource I can find states its the native compiler of XCode, but I have that installed...

Could someone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the Xcode assembler:

**> man as**

```
NAME
       as - Mac OS X Mach-O GNU-based assemblers

SYNOPSIS
       as [ option ...  ] [ file ...  ]

DESCRIPTION
       The as command translates assembly code in the named files to object code.
       If no files are specified, as reads from stdin.  All undefined symbols  in
       the assembly are treated as global.  The output of the assembly is left in
       the file a.out by default.

       The program /usr/bin/as is actually a driver that executes assemblers  for
       specific target architectures.  If no target architecture is specified, it
       defaults to the architecture of the host it is running on.
```

Do you have Xcode **and** it's cmd line tools installed?

```
> which as 
/usr/bin/as

> file `which as`
/usr/bin/as: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Located in Xcode.app:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../libexec/as/x86_64/as
```

Xcode cmd-line tools:

Assuming you have installed the 'free' Xcode package via the App store, the cmd line tools can be installed via "xcode-select". Drop into a term window and:

**xcode-select --help**

```
Usage: xcode-select [options]

Print or change the path to the active developer directory. This directory
controls which tools are used for the Xcode command line tools (for example,
xcodebuild) as well as the BSD development commands (such as cc and make).

Options:
  -h, --help                  print this help message and exit
  -p, --print-path            print the path of the active developer directory
  -s <path>, --switch <path>  set the path for the active developer directory
  --install                   open a dialog for installation of the command line developer tools
  -v, --version               print the xcode-select version
  -r, --reset                 reset to the default command line tools path
```

**xcode-select --install**

Once installed, you will get updates via the App Store

Comment: Are the command-line tools a separate package in the app store or is it something I can install once I have Xcode, and if so, how?

Comment: Thanks a ton! With your initial guidance I managed to find the Downloads-section in Xcode and installed it from there. Cheers!

Comment: Great... I forgot about that option in the IDE, always did it via the cmd line ;-)